# Right click start

Tags: c#, windows, right-click

I want to start a program from the right click menu,
here is sample, program is changing some of the text from a text file and saving it back at the same file..
i improvised a lot, so when program starts i press button then browse for a file, change what it needs and write it back again, but, i think it would be a lot faster if i can right-clink on file, and click on program, everything done without opening program..
is this even posible :)
thx

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {


        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog(); 
        string filename = "";
        string path = "";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(ofd.FileName);
        }

            System.IO.StreamReader ObjReader;
            ObjReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(path, Encoding.Default);
            textBox1.Text = ObjReader.ReadToEnd();
            ObjReader.Close();
            .
            .
            // do something
            .
            .
            System.IO.StreamWriter ObjWritter;
            ObjWritter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path);
            ObjWritter.Write(textBox1.Text);
            ObjWritter.Close();
            Application.Exit();



    }
```

Comment: yea c# win8, sory about that..

Comment: How is the code sample relevant to your question?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to add your application exe to Windows Explorer context menu.

For a example, check this how-to

http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you need to add to add your application to Explorer's right click.For Example : Consider you application is **Notepad** and you want to add an entry to open any file in Notepad.To start create a new key named *Send to Notepad* at the following path in **regedit.exe** :

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell
```

Then in **Send to Notepad** create a new key named *command*, then add the following command to **Default** entry of command.Or just add [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/afq2aze377jowfy/ContextMenu%20Entry.reg) key by double clicking it.

When you've created or added the keys try right clicking a file (better select a text file), you'll see there an entry named "Send to Notepad".If you click it the file will be opened in Notepad.

Hope this is enough to provide you with a good start.